# Have different zsh themes for terminal and iTerm

Tags: terminal, zsh, iterm, iterm2

Here is the problem. I am currently using `agnoster` theme in zsh. It looks great in iTerm but looks like this in terminal.

[image: Ugly terminal]

In other words it looks really ugly. So I am interested in two kinds of solutions:

1. Have different zsh themes for terminal and iTerm. So I can use agnoster for iTerm and some other theme for terminal. (For example: `robbyrussell` looks fine in terminal so I would like to have `agnoster` for iTerm and `robbyrussell` for terminal.
2. Make some modifications so that `agnoster` looks fine in terminal.

---

I got it to work, apparently I was missing a whitespace in my if condition, that rendered it completely useless. Here is how it looks in my `zshrc`

```
if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" = "Apple_Terminal" ]; then
    ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
else
    ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did the same for the Jetbrains terminal (`pyCharm` and `idea`):  

```if [ "$TERMINAL_EMULATOR" = "JetBrains-JediTerm" ]; then  
    ZSH_THEME="fwalch"  
else  
    ZSH_THEME="agnoster"  
fi```

Comment: I was in the exact same situation and your condition worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Terminal** and **iTerm** set the environmental variable `TERM_PROGRAM`.

`Terminal :    Apple_Terminal`

`iTerm    :    iTerm`

If you use `PathFinder`'s terminal, `TERM_PROGRAM` is unset.

Open your *oh-my-zsh* configuration and use the following construction:

```
OHMYTHEMES=(
    # your favourite themes
)


[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" = "iTerm" ] && OHMYTHEMES+=agnoster

ZSH_THEME=${OHMYTHEMES[(($RANDOM % ${#OHMYTHEMES} + 1))]} # chooses theme among your favourite randomly
```

As far as you know what is `zsh`, I assume you know the least bit of shell scripting and can adjust this to your code.

**Related question : [Get terminal application name from shell](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193437/get-terminal-application-name-from-shell)**

Comment: I had got it to work. Thanks for your reply though. I was missing a whitespace after `"$TERM_PROGRAM" in my if condition that was causing the error.

Comment: Not a problem, don't worry.

Comment: as an aside, such questions are for superuser and askdifferent.